# Add Quantity Field On Shop Page for WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to Add Quantity Field On Shop Page for WooCommerce. I added below code in archive-product.php file. I got the input field. but when I select multiple quantity, it is taken as 1 quantity. (in the cart it is added 1 QTY)

I added same code in home page. it is working fine. only issue in the shop page.

```
<div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
   <?php
       do_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity');
       
woocommerce_quantity_input(array(
        'min_value'   => apply_filters('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product),
        'max_value'   => apply_filters('woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product),
        'input_value' => isset($_POST['quantity']) ? wc_stock_amount(wp_unslash($_POST['quantity'])) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(),));

do_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity');

   ?>
</div>
```

here is the full code of the shop page

```
<div class="product_cart justify-content-center">
                      <?php
                      global $product;

                      if (!$product->is_purchasable()) {
                        return;
                      }

                      echo wc_get_stock_html($product); // WPCS: XSS ok.

                      if ($product->is_in_stock()) : ?>

                        <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form'); ?>
                        <?php if ($product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') || $product->is_type('grouped')) { ?>
                        <div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center">
                              <?php
                              do_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity');

                              woocommerce_quantity_input(array(
                                  'min_value'   => apply_filters('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), $product),
                                  'max_value'   => apply_filters('woocommerce_quantity_input_max', $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(), $product),
                                  'input_value' => isset($_POST['quantity']) ? wc_stock_amount(wp_unslash($_POST['quantity'])) : $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(), // WPCS: CSRF ok, input var ok.
                              ));

                              do_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity');

                              ?>
                          </div>

                          <form class="w-100 cart" action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                            <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button'); ?>

                            <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr($product->get_id()); ?>" class="btn btn-add-to-cart">Add to cart</button><?php echo do_shortcode('[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]'); ?>


                            <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button'); ?>
                          </form>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                          <form class="w-100 cart" action="<?php echo esc_url(apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink())); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                            <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button'); ?>

                            <button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr($product->get_id()); ?>" class="btn btn-add-to-cart">Add to cart</button><?php echo do_shortcode('[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist]'); ?>

                            <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button'); ?>
                          </form>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form'); ?>

                      <?php endif; ?>


                    </div>
                  </div>
```